# Numerical iteration method

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

A function is given such that $ f(x)=0 $ and it can be written as $ x=g(x)$. Now, we have to determine the root of $f(x)$ (the value of x so that $ f(x)=0$).  My textbook states that only when $|g’(a)|<1$ ( a is a random value of the function) , by using $x=a$ in interatio n method, the value of the root will be converging. In other words when $ |g’(a)|>1$, we can't determine the root because the value we get by using iterative method is diverging.

Is it true?
For instance, $$f(x)=x^3-2x+3$$
$$g(x)=(2x-3)^\frac{1}{3}$$
By using $ x=1.6 $ in iteration method, the root is equal to $1.893$. But $g’(x)=1.949$ which isn't less than 1.
I am wrong or the textbook is wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post what the textbook says about this verbatim.  That way we can definitively tell you if you are misinterpreting it or if the book is wrong.

Comment: Could you please check the signs on your reported numbers? Your numbers should all be negative, as the roots of the polynomial are $  0.9466445981522489   \pm  0.8297035528624056 i$ and $-1.8932891963044978$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you claim the book says is certainly not true. The condition $|g'(a)|<1$ must hold not for a random number $a$, but for $a$ the root of the equation.

What the book probably explains is that if $|g'(x)|<1$ for all $x$, then you can pick at random the first point of the iteration, and the sequence of iterations will converge to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

$g'(x)=\frac 23(2x-3)^{-2/3}$ and evaluated at $x=1.893$ gives $g'(1.893)=0.782757 \lt 1$

Answer (score 0):

The most basic form of the theorem says that if $x_0$ is close enough to the root $x$ and $|g'(x)|<1$, then the fixed point iteration converges. This version doesn't say how close "close enough" is.

A slightly more precise version of the theorem says that if you have a neighborhood of $x$, call it $N$, such that for any $y \in N$ you have $|g'(y)|<1$, and $x_0 \in N$, then the fixed point iteration converges.

The condition $|g'(x)|<1$ is very nearly necessary. The only way for fixed point iteration to converge to $x$ without this condition is for one of the iterates of the sequence to be exactly equal to $x$, which almost never happens.

By contrast, the hypothesis of the second version of the theorem implies that in particular $|g'(x_0)|<1$. This condition is far from being necessary. For example, if $g(x)=\frac{x+1/x}{2}$, then the iteration converges for any $x_0 \neq 0$.